# generic method parameter in enum

Tags: java, enums, generic-programming

I have a scenario where I need to have a method in enum which accepts a generic type and returns String

```
public enum Test{
   EMPLOYEE(){
      @Override
       public String write(Employee e){
        //logic
       },
//similar entries
;

public abstract <T> String write(T t);

}
```

I keep getting an error in the override saying “method doesn’t override from superclass”. Does anyone know what’s missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: The signature of the enum's method must be `public <T> String write(T e){` as well

Comment: But inside the enum I want to pass specific object, not T. Isn’t that possible?

Comment: [What you actually need is a class-level type parameter](https://ideone.com/R0FVoM), but it's not possible with enum. (Method-level type parameters don't work the way you are thinking they do. You can't override them like that.)

Comment: There’s no sense in a declaration like `<T> String write(T t)` as the *caller* decides what to use for `T`, hence, this method has to accept any type argument for the parameter, so in absence of any other constraint, it’s not different to `String write(Object o)`.